# Most efficient way to transform array of JS objects to nested form?

Tags: javascript, arrays, normalization

I want to transform:

```
[
    {id: 1, name: 'one', desc: 'one'},
    {id: 2, name: 'two', desc: 'two'},
    {id: 3, name: 'three', desc: 'three'}
]
```

to

```
{
    1: {id: 1, name: 'one', desc: 'one'},
    2: {id: 2, name: 'two', desc: 'two'},
    3: {id: 3, name: 'three', desc: 'three'}
}
```

What is the most efficient/performant way to do this? Some options would be:

1) https://github.com/gaearon/normalizr

2) `d3.nest()`

3) `const object = {}; array.forEach(item => { object[item.id] = item });`

Comment: You already have an object in that configuration, only it starts at 0 instead of 1. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I like `Array.prototype.reduce()` solutions. Check this out

```js
var arr = [{id: 1, name: 'one', desc: 'one'}, {id: 2, name: 'two', desc: 'two'}, {id: 3, name: 'three', desc: 'three'}],
    obj = arr.reduce((p,c) => {p[c.id] = c; return p},{});

document.write("<pre>" + JSON.stringify(obj,null,2) + "</pre>");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a simple loop:

```
var arr = [{id: 1, name: 'one', desc: 'one'}, {id: 2, name: 'two', desc: 'two'}, {id: 3, name: 'three', desc: 'three'}],
    obj = {}
for(var item of arr) obj[item.id] = item;
```

Usually loops are faster than ES5 array methods because they don't have to call a function at each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that it is:

```
const obj = Object.assign( {}, array );
```

Although, I haven't compared its performance to your options.

Comment: That doesn't work, OP wants to assign them by their `.id` not by their index in the array.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```js
ar = [
    {id: 1, name: 'one', desc: 'one'},
    {id: 2, name: 'two', desc: 'two'},
    {id: 3, name: 'three', desc: 'three'}
]

var result = ar.reduce((ac, x) => {return ac[x.id] = x , ac ;}, {})

document.write( JSON.stringify(result) )
```

but remember that the keys are strings and you're dealing with an object not array...